# How to fix a WordPress edit beta white blank page?

Tags: wordpress

I created a site using local wp and created a new theme using VSCode. When I tried to open the edit beta page to edit my site I got a white blank page and I got no errors.

When I use the devtools to inspect, I find all the HTML elements and no network errors. I tried every solution I could find on internet but I couldn't resolve it.

Here is the editor page I got :

[image: 1]

Can you please give me a solution?

Comment: Turn on [debugging mode](https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/debugging-in-wordpress/) for WordPress and it’ll show you the errors.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to navigate to the root of your project and open the wp-config.php file. There you'll find the following:

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', false );
```

If it is set to "false" you'll want to change it to "true" to allow WordPress to show error output on the page you are getting the white screen.

If you did not find the above script in the wp-config.php file you'll want to add the following.

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
```

When you do you'll likely see a "Fatal" error that is causing the site to crash and information on the file and line in the code where you can find the offending script.